# How to Set Icon to display on the far right in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.addicon);
```

The code above seems to place my Icon in the Centre . I would like to place to the far right and make it clickable as well . At the moment it the image for the icon is in the project files as a drawable I have not included it in any xml files.

Comment: you need to create custom toolbar with image view inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` in your toolbar xml for place it to right and

set below code for clickable :

```
getSupportActionbar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and :

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Do stuff
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches for doing that.

1. [Option Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)
2. Creating custom toolbar.

### With Option Menus

create `main.xml` under res/menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.ioa.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_addition"
        android:icon="@drawable/addicon"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Addition"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

and inside your activity create menu like,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

you can perform Action on particular menu item.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem Item) {

    if (Item.getItemId() == R.id.action_addition) {
        // perform action
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(paramMenuItem);
}
```

### With custom toolbar

Create your `ToolBar` like this,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and now you can perform click event of particular `ImageView`.

```
ImageView add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add);

add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do work.
        }
    });
```

happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You Need 3 Things:

1. A Custom Toolbar Layout
2. Include the toolbar in your activity
3. Set the Logo to the toolbar

*Create new Resource Layout:*
*include_toolbar.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/include_toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

*Change Your Activity File: MainActivity.java*

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.include_toolbar); 
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap_ic_launcher);
}
}
```

And here's the styles.xml:

```
<!-- language: xml-->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    </resources>
```